# What am I doing wrong with this loop?

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

[image]

So in the second picture is what I want to happen if the user puts in 0 for the name. But I want the program to loop until they do so in the first picture I'm trying to do that by saying to loop the main() until anything other than zero is entered. Is the loop in the wrong spot or is something else just completely off?

Comment: Paste the formatted code in question.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors,  copy/paste your code into the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it when you use input(), you will get a string not a int. And '0' != 0 . So you need to change you code into `name != '0'`

Answer (score 0):

you are getting it wrong, what you are saying is different from what you are coding, you have to first check if the user enters 0 or not, if the user doesn't enter the right number or value they are mandated to keep trying, you really don't need a loop but a conditional operator or function that keeps checking for the 0 in the main method. that way you will get your desired result. 
e.g

```
name = int(input())
if(name!=0):
   name =input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
flag = 1
while flag:
    name = input("Enter Name or 0 to quit: ")
    if name !='0':
        main()
    else:
        flag = 0
```

Comment: it doesn't quit the program still its still looping back to the enter name input

Comment: try while flag == 1